# AdvancedDataGrid total sum of branch nodes

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, advanceddatagrid

**Introduction:**
I have an AdvancedDataGrid displaying hierarchical data illustrated by the image below:
[image]

The branch nodes "Prosjekt" and "Tiltak" display the sum of the leaf nodes below.

**Problem:** I want the root node "Tavle" to display the total sum of the branch nodes below. When i attempted to do this by adding the same SummaryRow the sum of the root node was not calculcated correctly(Every node's sum was calculated twice).

```
dg_Teknikktavles = new AutoSizingAdvancedDataGrid();
            dg_Teknikktavles.sortExpertMode="true";
            dg_Teknikktavles.headerHeight = 50;
            dg_Teknikktavles.variableRowHeight = true;

            dg_Teknikktavles.addEventListener(ListEvent.ITEM_CLICK,dg_TeknikktavlesItemClicked);
            dg_Teknikktavles.editable="false";
            dg_Teknikktavles.percentWidth=100;
            dg_Teknikktavles.minColumnWidth =0.8;
            dg_Teknikktavles.height = 1000;
            var sumFieldArray:Array = new Array(context.brukerList.length);

            for(var i:int = 0; i < context.brukerList.length; i++)
            {
            var sumField:SummaryField2 = new SummaryField2();
            sumField.dataField = Ressurstavle.ressursKey + i;
            sumField.summaryOperation = "SUM";
            sumFieldArray[i] = sumField;
            }

            var summaryRow:SummaryRow = new SummaryRow();
            summaryRow.summaryPlacement = "group";
            summaryRow.fields = sumFieldArray;

            var summaryRow2:SummaryRow = new SummaryRow();
            summaryRow2.summaryPlacement = "group";
            summaryRow2.fields = sumFieldArray;

            var groupField1:GroupingField = new GroupingField();
            groupField1.name = "tavle";
            //groupField1.summaries = [summaryRow2];

            var groupField2:GroupingField = new GroupingField();
            groupField2.name = "kategori";
            groupField2.summaries = [summaryRow];
            var group:Grouping = new Grouping();
            group.fields = [groupField1, groupField2];
            var groupCol:GroupingCollection2 = new GroupingCollection2();
            groupCol.source = ressursTavle;
            groupCol.grouping = group;
            groupCol.refresh();
```

**Main Question:** How do i get my AdvancedDataGrid's (dg_Teknikktavles) root node "Tavle" to correctly display the sum of the two branch nodes below?

**Side Question:** How do i add a red color to the numbers of the root node's summary row that exceed 5? E.g the column displaying 8 will exceed 5 in the root node's summary row, and should therefore be marked red

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone else has the same problem:

The initial problem that everything was summed twice, was the result of using the same Array of SummaryField2 (*sumFieldArray* in the code) for both grouping fields(GropingField2 *tavle* and *kategori*)

**The Solution to the main question:** was to create a new array of summaryfields for the root node(in my intial for loop):

```
    //Summary fields for root node
    var sumFieldRoot:SummaryField2 = new SummaryField2();
    sumFieldRoot.dataField = Ressurstavle.ressursKey + i;
    sumFieldRoot.summaryOperation = "SUM";
    sumFieldArrayRoot[i] = sumFieldRoot;
```

**Answer to the side question:**
This was pretty much as easy as pointed out by wvxyw. Code for this solution below:

```
        private function summary_styleFunction(data:Object, col:AdvancedDataGridColumn):Object
        {
            var output:Object;
            var field:String = col.dataField; 
            if ( data.children != null )  
            {  
                if(data[field] >5){
                    output = {color:0xFF0000, fontWeight:"bold"}
                }
                else {
                    output = {color:0x006633, fontWeight:"bold"}
                }
                //output = {color:0x081EA6, fontWeight:"bold", fontSize:14}

            }  


            return output;  
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a general answer, without code examples, but I had to do the same just couple of days ago, so my memory is still fresh :) Here's what I did:

1. Created a class A to represent an item renderer data, extended it from Proxy (I had field names defined at run time), and let it contain a collection of values as it's data member. Once accessed through `flash_proxy::getPropery(fieldName)` it would find a corresponding value in the data member containing the values and return it. *Special note: implement `IUID`, just do it, it'll save you couple of days of frustration*.
2. Extended A in B, added a `children` property containing ArrayCollection of A (don't try to experiment with other collection types, unless you want to find yourself examining tons of framework code, trust me, it's ugly and is impossible to identify as interesting). Let B override `flash_proxy::getPropery` - depending of your compiler this may, or may not be possible, if not possible - call some function from `A.flash_proxy::getPropery()` that you can override in B. Let this function query every instance of A, which is a child of B, asking the same thing, as DataGrid itself would, when building item renderers - this way you would get the total.
3. When creating a data provider. Create an ArrayCollection of B (again, don't try to experiment with other collections--unless you are ready for lots of frustration). Create Hierarchical data that uses this array collection as a source.

Colors - that's what you use item renderers for, just look up any tutorial on using item renderers, that must be pretty basic.

Comment: Thank you for your help and a good answer! I found the solution to my problem(for more information read my answer). The solution was a bit simpler than i expected :p